# Interactive Legend for focus + context using dimple.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, legend, dimple.js

I've built a multi-line focus+context visualization using d3.js and made a legend with code from [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887118). I've been playing around with the interactive legend example from dimple.js ([here!](http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_interactive_legends)) and tried inplemented the code into my already existing code, but an error comes up where it says "e.aggField" is not defined. Is this error due to the fact I'm not making a scatterplot using dimple.js, or that the legend code I already have does not work with the interactive part I'm trying to put in? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the dimple example assumes you have used dimple and therefore that dimple's field structure is present.  You should be able to modify the code though, aggfield just contains an array of strings by which the series is disaggregated. So in the dimple example because the series is defined as:

```
 myChart.addSeries(["SKU", "Channel", "Owner"], dimple.plot.bubble);
```

The topmost bubble for example will have a data row with an aggField value of:

```
["Theta 18 Pack Standard", "Hypermarkets", "Black Mesa"]
```

You just need to replace the code to use the corresponding values from your dataset.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense. So since I'm trying to draw a focus+context, I would have to clarify the series from my data and use dimple.plot.area instead of dimple.plot.bubble, right?